# Get file names in VS2010 project using T4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t4

I'm trying to use T4 with VS2010 to enumerate files in a project, run a custom tool on files that have a certain extension, and then add generated files to the solution. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the names of the files in my projects. I looked at EnvDTE and couldn't locate a function that would do this. Does my approach even make sense? I'm trying to use T4 more like a VS2010 scripting tool than anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good luck. No, seriously.  EnvDTE isn't the most friendly interface.

Long story short, from the Solution [EnvDTE.Solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dte.solution.aspx) you must iterate the projects within the solution ([Solution.Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.projects.aspx)) and then enumerate (*recursively!*) the ProjectItems in the Project ([Project.ProjectItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.projectitems.aspx)) and get the filenames for each ProjectItem ([ProjectItem.FileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitem.filenames.aspx)).

There are many stumbling points involved in this.  ProjectItems may represent the References node in the Project, a folder, or other items which don't actually have files associated with them.  Also, a single ProjectItem may have multiple files (think of class.cs and class.designer.cs).  And, to top it all off, DTE is just a crappy COM wrapper and feels like one.

Comment: Following from Will's answer, is it a strict requirement that the files have to be members of the solution?  I.e. could you start from the location of the SLN file and just query the file system?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - I'm debating that. I think I need people to opt in to this unfortunately